# Problems installing Folding@home (unmet dependencies ... not installable)

Tags: software-installation, python, dependencies, 19.10, gnome2

I am trying to install [Folding@home](https://foldingathome.org/start-folding/) to my Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) though `Eddy`, but I receive the following error message:

```
com.github.donadigo.eddy
Installation Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    fahcontrol: Depends python-gnome2 but it is not installable
```

The package names are the following:

```
fahclient_7.5.1_amd64.deb
fahcontrol_7.5.1-1_all.deb
fahviewer_7.5.1_amd64.deb
```

I'd like to start contributing to the Covid-19 project, but I don't know what to do next. I hope you can help me out!

Comment: Duplicate. [How to install folding at home (Folding@home FAHControl) on Ubuntu 19.10
](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217195/how-to-install-folding-at-home-foldinghome-fahcontrol-on-ubuntu-19-10) already resolved the problem.

Comment: Yepp... That one answered my question. Facing a different problem now (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220685/fahclient-cannot-connect-on-ubuntu-19-10), the client cannot connect anymore.