# FAHClient cannot connect on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: connection, error-handling, debugging, debug

I've been running `FAHClient` successfully for one day now, and hence been contributing to the protein folding project. ... Well, I was until I recently booted my system. Now, the client won't connect, neither run through Terminal nor the graphical UI.

With my Windows 10 machine the client runs and connects just fine. I am only having this problem with my Ubuntu (19.10 Eoan Ermite, rather a recent install). Please find the error logs below:

```
 XXXXs@ubuntu:~$ FAHClient
11:18:18:************************* Folding@home Client *************************
11:18:18:    Website: https://foldingathome.org/
11:18:18:  Copyright: (c) 2009-2018 foldingathome.org
11:18:18:     Author: Joseph Coffland <joseph@cauldrondevelopment.com>
11:18:18:       Args: 
11:18:18:     Config: <none>
11:18:18:******************************** Build ********************************
11:18:18:    Version: 7.5.1
11:18:18:       Date: May 11 2018
11:18:18:       Time: 19:59:04
11:18:18: Repository: Git
11:18:18:   Revision: 4705bf53c635f88b8fe85af7675557e15d491ff0
11:18:18:     Branch: master
11:18:18:   Compiler: GNU 6.3.0 20170516
11:18:18:    Options: -std=gnu++98 -O3 -funroll-loops
11:18:18:   Platform: linux2 4.14.0-3-amd64
11:18:18:       Bits: 64
11:18:18:       Mode: Release
11:18:18:******************************* System ********************************
11:18:18:        CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
11:18:18:     CPU ID: GenuineIntel Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9
11:18:18:       CPUs: 4
11:18:18:     Memory: 31.17GiB
11:18:18:Free Memory: 29.11GiB
11:18:18:    Threads: POSIX_THREADS
11:18:18: OS Version: 5.3
11:18:18:Has Battery: true
11:18:18: On Battery: false
11:18:18: UTC Offset: 2
11:18:18:        PID: 3746
11:18:18:        CWD: /home/XXXXs
11:18:18:         OS: Linux 5.3.0-7642-generic x86_64
11:18:18:    OS Arch: AMD64
11:18:18:       GPUs: 0
11:18:18:       CUDA: Not detected: Failed to open dynamic library 'libcuda.so':
11:18:18:             libcuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
11:18:18:             directory
11:18:18:     OpenCL: Not detected: Failed to open dynamic library 'libOpenCL.so':
11:18:18:             libOpenCL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
11:18:18:             directory
11:18:18:***********************************************************************
11:18:18:<config>
11:18:18:  <!-- Folding Slots -->
11:18:18:</config>
11:18:18:Connecting to assign1.foldingathome.org:8080
11:18:19:Updated GPUs.txt
11:18:19:Read GPUs.txt
11:18:19:Trying to access database...
11:18:19:Successfully acquired database lock
11:18:19:Enabled folding slot 00: PAUSED cpu:1 (not configured)
11:18:19:ERROR:Exception: Could not bind socket to 0.0.0.0:7396: Address already in use
11:18:19:ERROR:Exception: Could not bind socket to 0.0.0.0:36330: Address already in use
11:19:20:Saving configuration to config.xml
11:19:20:<config>
11:19:20:  <!-- Folding Slots -->
11:19:20:  <slot id='0' type='CPU'/>
11:19:20:</config>
11:19:20:Set client configured
11:19:20:WU00:FS00:Connecting to 65.254.110.245:8080
11:19:22:WU00:FS00:Connecting to 65.254.110.245:8080
11:19:23:WARNING:WU00:FS00:Failed to get assignment from '65.254.110.245:8080': No WUs available for this configuration
11:19:23:WU00:FS00:Connecting to 18.218.241.186:80
11:19:23:WARNING:WU00:FS00:Failed to get assignment from '18.218.241.186:80': No WUs available for this configuration
11:19:23:ERROR:WU00:FS00:Exception: Could not get an assignment
11:19:23:WU00:FS00:Connecting to 65.254.110.245:8080
11:19:24:WARNING:WU00:FS00:Failed to get assignment from '65.254.110.245:8080': No WUs available for this configuration
11:19:24:WU00:FS00:Connecting to 18.218.241.186:80
11:19:24:WARNING:WU00:FS00:Failed to get assignment from '18.218.241.186:80': No WUs available for this configuration
11:19:24:ERROR:WU00:FS00:Exception: Could not get an assignment
```

Comment: Here's a [related post](https://foldingforum.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=30228) from the folding forums, and [another](https://www.reddit.com/r/Folding/comments/fjqqwm/help_failed_to_get_assignmentno_wus_available_for/) from reddit. The reddit link suggests this error may be due to a large volume of people folding.

Comment: @David thanks! Haven't read through both of the posts, though the first one already answered my question. Considering the drastic peak from 100,000 volunteers to 400,000 volunteers on such a short time-span, it seems that the server responsible for delegating the `working units`(WUs) is has become overloaded.

The best 'workaround'  — if you may — is to run `FAHClient` instead of `FAHControl` (i.e. the one through Terminal instead of the graphical UI). Well, for me it took some 60 minutes before the client was able to connect and get a WU. After that, I lauchec the graphical UI normally.

Comment: I've been having some problems with the FAH client on Ubuntu, it seems like it might not be as efficient as the Windows client, because on my virtual machine (running Windows 10) the FAH client connects almost instantaneously and pulls a work order.

Comment: @David I've just added my old HP EliteBook 820 (running Windows 10 as well) to reinforce my "Covid-19 home laboratory", but I have to say that I haven't noticed any clear pattern or tendency w.r.t. which one of the three laptops (one Linux, two Windows) do have more problems connecting. Seems to be random, and currently my Windows EliteBook has been without a WU for a few hours already. Some do say that pausing — re - folding (or repeating the cycle, at least) would help. And every time one WU is completed, there's the risk that another one is not appointed to your CPU/GPU immediately. Cheers!

Comment: However, it seems that my Linux is **only** running on CPU  &#x1f633;