# Unable to install FAHControl on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I'm trying to install FAHControl on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop but I keep getting the following errors:

```
 fahcontrol depends on python; however:
  Package python is not installed.
 fahcontrol depends on python-gtk2 | python-gnome2; however:
  Package python-gtk2 is not installed.
  Package python-gnome2 is not installed.
```

I tried to install python-gtk2 but apt is unable to locate package python-gtk2.
Following the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217195/how-to-install-folding-at-home-foldinghome-fahcontrol-on-ubuntu-19-10) to create python-gnome2 did help me install the package but it wouldn't launch.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of force-installing deprecated Python2 packages, you could go forward with a **[Python3 fork of FAHControl](https://github.com/cdberkstresser/fah-control)** ([see this discussion](https://foldingforum.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=34757&sid=8ca4c8cdfc45eb3551aef6b192f3e37a&start=15)), which works fine for me. The Readme describes as precondition:

```sh
apt install python3-stdeb python3-gi python3-all python3-six debhelper dh-python gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```

I reduced this quite a bit, as not all packages are needed (e.g. `python3-stdeb` and `debhelper` are only needed for packaging, and some other packages were already installed) – and ended up with `apt install python3-all` being sufficient. YMMV, but what definitely suffices is

```sh
apt install python3-gi python3-all python3-six dh-python gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```

Following that, either download and `apt install` [the only existing `*.deb` file](https://github.com/cdberkstresser/fah-control/releases) (dating back to 4/2020) – or install the latest version from source, which is what I did:

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/cdberkstresser/fah-control.git
cd fah-control
echo "version = '7.7.0'" > fah/Version.py
./FAHControl
```

(instead of `git clone` you can of course also download and unpack the archive).

Now, to get *FAHControl* into your application menu, adjust `FAHControl.desktop` (the path for `Exec`, `TryExec` and `Icon`), then copy it to `~/.local/share/applications`, and you are done. From time to time, check for updates (e.g. `git pull origin master` when you cloned from Git) to get the latest fixes.

Answer (score 9):

The Python 2 is now deprecated, so its parts got removed from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

But the `python-gtk2` may be downloaded manually and then proceed with installation of `fahcontrol` by:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://download.foldingathome.org/releases/public/release/fahcontrol/debian-stable-64bit/v7.6/fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb
```

For 21.10 the command list is longer:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://download.foldingathome.org/releases/public/release/fahcontrol/debian-stable-64bit/v7.6/fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-12ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-cairo_1.16.2-1_amd64.deb ./python-gobject-2_2.28.6-12ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb ./fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb
```

Comment: This doesn't fully works on Ubuntu 21.10: 
`python-gtk2 : Depends: python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1) but it is not installable               Depends: python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3) but it is not installable`

Comment: Ok, thanks, fixed.

Comment: Thank you, N0rbert! Now it works on my machine!

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution after 3 days of research, finally i get Fahcontrol installed on my Ubunto 21.04, the solution is:

**1 download** Fahviewer/Fahclient/Fahcontrol from folding@home website:https://foldingathome.org/start-folding/

**2 install** Fahviewer and Fahclient first (it's easy u won't face a problem), how to do that? it's easy, open terminal (search for it on search tap), write "cd Downloads/" and hit enter write ll (double L to see ur all downloads), it  appear like that on my terminal:

hassan@hassan-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ ll

total 9024

-rwxrwxr-x  1 hassan hassan 3266064 ماي    31 11:52 fahclient_7.6.21_amd64.deb*

-rw-rw-r--  1 hassan hassan  145292 ماي    31 11:52 fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb

-rw-rw-r--  1 hassan hassan 4664692 ماي    31 11:52 fahviewer_7.6.21_amd64.deb

hassan@hassan-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$

**install Fahviewer**

hassan@hassan-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./fahviewer_7.6.21_amd64.deb
(u might have a newer version of Fahviewer than me so change the version number or copy the whole file name).
click enter and enter ur password and hit enter again (it will install after that).
Do the same thing with fahclient.

**3 Install Fahcontrol**: Do this as i did

write this command: sudo apt install ./fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb
(u might have a newer version of Fahcontrol than me so change the version number or copy the whole file name).
If the output like this i have the solution:

hassan@hassan-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'fahcontrol' instead of './fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
fahcontrol : Depends: python-gtk2 but it is not installable or
python-gnome2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

```
                         **Solution**
```

-**search on google for python-gtk2** and download it (it will be like this: python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb)

-**install it:** sudo apt install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

(u might have a newer version than me so change the version number or just copy the whole file name).

If the output like this don't worry i have it's solution:

hassan@hassan-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-gtk2' instead of './python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-gtk2 : Depends: python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

**-it's solution is:** search for python-cairo deb on google or (better) go to https://pkgs.org/download/python-cairo look for ur Distribution (for me it's Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)), there is 2 python-cairo, download the first one "python-cairo......amd64.deb" and install it (i will show u how to do that) if it work with u that's great if not try the second one "python-cairo......arm64.deb",

-**go back to terminal** and now let's install python-cairo(arm64.deb/amd64.deb) write this command: sudo apt install ./python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb (it will show like this):

hassan@hassan-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-cairo' instead of './python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
python-cairo
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/57.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 270 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/hassan/Downloads/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb python-cairo amd64 1.16.2-2ubuntu2 [57.1 kB]
Selecting previously unselected package python-cairo:amd64.
(Reading database ... 210079 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-cairo:amd64 (1.16.2-2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python-cairo:amd64 (1.16.2-2ubuntu2) ...
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/hassan/Downloads/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

-**then enter this command:** sudo apt update (it will take some seconds to update)

-**after that let's install Fahcontrol**, write and enter this command:
sudo apt install ./fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb
(u might have a newer version than me so change the version number or just copy the whole file name).
-it should install fahcontrol without a missing dependencies (it will shows like this):

hassan@hassan-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'fahcontrol' instead of './fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
fahcontrol
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/145 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,323 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/hassan/Downloads/fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb fahcontrol all 7.6.21-1 [145 kB]
Selecting previously unselected package fahcontrol.
(Reading database ... 210111 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fahcontrol (7.6.21-1) ...
Setting up fahcontrol (7.6.21-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.68ubuntu1) ...
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/hassan/Downloads/fahcontrol_7.6.21-1_all.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

-**Congratulations** Finally u will be able to use Fahcontrol instead of webcontrol.

-to start floding open Fahcontrol first then write this on terminal:
sudo /etc/init.d/FAHClient start

-find more information about floding@home here:https://foldingathome.org/support/faq/installation-guides/linux/command-line-options/

[**Screenshot of Fahcontrol on my ubunto 21.04**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuVst.png)

Comment: What does this add on top of the existing answer?

Comment: i don't got it.

Comment: The accepted answer explains exactly what you did but isn't a wall of text written like an article for a blog.